# Unable to match regex

Tags: php, regex

I have got the following phrase:

```
Mark: 5   Mike   2015-01-20
```

and I need to get Mike from it. I have tried to use negative lookups like this:

```
/^(\s+)((?!Mark\:(\d)).)*&(\w+)$/is
```

but it did not produce the desired result. Also there are some spaces in the begginning and the end of the phrase. Any ideas how to fix that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: $var = $trim($var); should trim leading and trailing spaces or tabs from the string, and would at least make your regex a bit simpler

Comment: Maybe [`\b[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/XEC4zS/1)? A whole word before a date string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Mark:<optional spaces><digits><optional spaces>` is a prefix
for the search string (our "*Mike*"), and the search string is a sequence of non-space
characters, then the following should do:

```
preg_match('/Mark\:\s*\d+\s*(\S+)/', $the_string, $m);
// $m[1] = 'Mike'
```

If the search string is supposed to be something more complex, then just replace `\S+`
with the desired pattern. You haven't specified this case, so I can't help
more.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the pattern `^\s*Mark: \d+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s*$`, then the first group will match what your looking for.  See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNAfjB/1).